# How to create an updates in ACTIVITY class [NEWBIE]

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to develop my own application in android and I want to update the information into DB so here my code 
/////////DB//////////

//--updates a record--

```
public boolean updateRecords(long columnId, String nAME ,String sURNAME,String dateOfBirth, String homeAddress,String emailNO, String phoneNumber, String city,String type_payment, String type_shipping,String cardNumber,String username, String passwords )




     {

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

            args.put(COLUMN_NAME,nAME);
            args.put(COLUMN_SURNAME,sURNAME);
            args.put(COLUMN_DATE_OF_BIRTH,dateOfBirth);
            args.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS,homeAddress);
            args.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,emailNO);
            args.put(COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER,phoneNumber);
            args.put(COLUMN_CITY,city);
            args.put(COLUMN_PTYE_PAYMENT,type_payment);
            args.put(COLUMN_SHIPPING_TYPE,type_shipping);
            args.put(COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER,cardNumber);
            args.put(COLUMN_username,username); 
            args.put(COLUMN_Password,passwords);





    return db.update(USERS_TABLE, args,COLUMN_ID + "= "+ columnId, null) > 0;

            }
```

And My ACTIVITY CLASS is like this ........................

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnEditSave){

        Log.d("test", "edited");     

//get data from form


 EditText NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtname);
   EditText SURNAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtSurname);
   EditText DateOfBirth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtID);
    EditText HomeAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtPAddress);
   EditText EmailNO = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtEmail);
   EditText PhoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtNumber);
   EditText City = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtCity);
   EditText type_payment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextspinnerPayment);
  EditText type_shipping = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSpinnerShipping);
   EditText CardNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtCardNumber);



EditText Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtUsername);
   EditText Passwords = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxtPassword);




Cursor value = null ;
    db.open();
    Log.d("test", "opened database"); 

    long columnId = value.getLong(value.getColumnIndex("ID"));
    //boolean
    if( db.updateRecords(columnId, NAME.getText().toString(),
                         SURNAME.getText().toString(),
                         DateOfBirth.getText().toString(),
                         HomeAddress.getText().toString(),
                         EmailNO.getText().toString(),
                         PhoneNumber.getText().toString(), 
                         City.getText().toString(), 
                         type_payment.getText().toString(),
                         type_shipping.getText().toString(),
                         CardNumber.getText().toString(), 
                         Username.getText().toString(),
                         Passwords.getText().toString())); 


              else
              {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }

db.close();
```

And I'm getting an error in logcast .......

```
06-02 16:29:48.518: D/dalvikvm(12573): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 5% free 7179K/7495K, paused 7ms+5ms
06-02 16:30:03.218: D/test(12573): edited
06-02 16:30:03.278: D/test(12573): opened database
06-02 16:30:03.278: D/AndroidRuntime(12573): Shutting down VM
06-02 16:30:03.278: W/dalvikvm(12573): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at com.sdc.editpersonalinfo.onClick(editpersonalinfo.java:119)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-02 16:30:03.320: E/AndroidRuntime(12573):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 16:35:03.524: I/Process(12573): Sending signal. PID: 12573 SIG: 9
06-02 16:35:05.550: V/TLINE(13716): new: android.text.TextLine@40684488
06-02 16:35:06.151: V/TLINE(13716): new: android.text.TextLine@406894b0
```

Comment: see line no 119 of editpersonalinfo.java ?

Comment: open your `editpersonalinfo.java` class and see line no.119,there are something null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are initializing "value" to null and then using it, so I think there is your NullPointerException:

```
Cursor value = null ;
db.open();
Log.d("test", "opened database"); 

long columnId = value.getLong(value.getColumnIndex("ID"));
```

Maybe it's a good idea if you have a look to this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

In Exercise 1 they explain how to deal with a sqlite database in Android.

Comment: ja! i understand that, but if im not initializing in giving me an error in this line...long columnId = value.getLong(value.getColumnIndex("ID")); 
ERRORS FOR VALUE

Comment: You should initialize cursor with a query to your db. This query returns a cursor that you can use to iterate through the results. In this case, you are trying to update a row in the table, but how do you know which row should be updated?

Comment: I mean the Cursor value = null. That should be initialized with a query to your database. Something like: Cursor value = db.query("your_table_name", columns, selection, args, groupBy, having, orderBy); Anyway, I think you don't need all this at all. If you are updating a row, you already know its ID because you have this data already(it's an update, not a creation). Use this ID (maybe stored in some array) in your db.update to update the correct row.

Comment: From where do you start your Activity called "editpersonalinfo.java"? I think there, in the previous activity to this one, you must have the ID of the user, something that identifies this user from others. You can pass this number as an extra when launching the activity "editpersonalinfo.java" and use it here to update the info.

Comment: Without more information about how your app is done, I cannot help you. Maybe it's good if you include the code where you create an user for the first time and you explain how the app works and how the user can edit his info.

Comment: I'm getting all info for a certain person from a database and display it into a EditText after that i want to edit  maybe a email address and then save it again..my problem i cant able to update the info..I'm looking for an updates based on the code i posted above..let me hope u understand me... :)

Comment: When you get all the info for a certain person you are also getting the ID if you have this field in the database (that is the way to identify an user). There, when getting the info, you should store this ID to use it later on the update. If you add to your answer the code where you get all this information, maybe I can help you to get the ID.

Comment: It does not want to just give me ur email